# Angular 2/4 - Remove component from DOM, but keep in memory

Tags: angular, dom, components, hidden

I'm trying to create multiple instances of the same component, and make them "tab-able" of a sort - basically only one of each component instance should be visible at a time.  The problem is that I know about the [hidden] directive, but it doesn't work for me because I've built this huge component using a lot of ID tags in the HTML and it breaks the CSS on all but one of the components when they are all existent in the DOM at the same time (CSS rules, ya know?).

My question is if there's a way to remove components from the DOM, but still keep them in memory (for data retension) to be re-inserted later? Thanks!

**Update:**

I was able to come up with a solution utilizing the abstract `RouteReuseStrategy`class. Info was taken from here:

https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2016/12/02/sticky-routes-in-angular-2-3-with-routereusestrategy.aspx

Comment: why not store that data in parent component or a service, then add `@Input`s to your component and make it accept that data.

Comment: @AhmedMusallam because I could have an arbitrary number of the same component, each with their own individual sets of data. Keeping a field in a parent component doesn't seem like the best option. Also that implies that the component will always be a child of that parent component, and that's something we're trying to avoid in this specific app.

Comment: thats why I also mentioned a 'service'. You can also add a dynamic route with an identifier for components and getting the data based on that identifier.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the `<router-outlet>` does if you use a reuse strategy that actually reuses component instances.
When you dynamically create a component

[source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/71f5b73296708014b740fb5dd0145c0599de7a19/packages/router/src/directives/router_outlet.ts#L112)

```
 this.activated = this.location.createComponent(factory, this.location.length, inj, []);
```

[source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/71f5b73296708014b740fb5dd0145c0599de7a19/packages/router/src/directives/router_outlet.ts#L72)

```
this.location.detach();
```

and the returned `r` is then passed to `attach(ref, ...)`

[source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/71f5b73296708014b740fb5dd0145c0599de7a19/packages/router/src/directives/router_outlet.ts#L82)

```
this.location.insert(ref.hostView);
```

Comment: That's interesting, seems a bit complex though (I'm pretty new to Angular and don't know about all the inner workings just yet). Do you think I could accomplish my goal by simply using the router?

Comment: If you want the status to reflect in the URL and the URL to get updated on tab change, then using a router is a good way.

Comment: I think using `detach` and `insert` isn't that complicated (haven't tried it myself yet though) and when you provide a Plunker in case you run into a problem, I'm sure someone will have a look.

Comment: The suggested service is a good idea, but it only keeps data and the view needs to be rebuilt. You mentioned that you have complex components, this is why I suggested `detach`/`insert`. Usually a service is the way to go.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: Update: the `detach` and `insert` methods didn't work. Nothing happened.  If the component needs to be created via the `createComponent` method, then I don't see how this can be done without reverse engineering a good chunk of angular. The variables used in this method are very difficult to reproduce.

Comment: Please try to reproduce in a plunker.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet for retaining data across components is to use a service. I have a simple example here: http://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/

I also have an example of a "tabbed" dialog using the . You can find that here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing in the APM-Final folder.

[image]

Comment: I was under the impression that services should only be used for business logic and passing data between components, not storing data. That could also get messy in my situation, as my app could have an arbitrary number of components all using the same instance of a service to store their data in.

Comment: You are correct in that you don't "store" data in a service. You'd use the service to retrieve the data *one time* and share it between the components. You can have multiple services, one for each major feature area. So a ProductService and an InvoiceService and a UserService and so on.